# Proving That the Only Possible Eigenvalue for a Linear Transformation is Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a linear algebra problem that I'm trying to solve. But my conclusion still lacks , and I do not know how to proceed. Here it is:

Given the following conditions:

- finite-dimensional vector space $V$
- a linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow V$. It holds for all $v, w$ in $V$ that $\langle\phi(v), w\rangle + \langle v, \phi(w)\rangle = 0$.
- Definition of eigenvalues: An eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear map $\phi$ is a real number such that there is a vector $v$ in $V$, not the zero vector, and $\phi(v) = \lambda \cdot v$ holds.

Show that: The only possible (real) Eigenvalue of $\phi$ has to be number 0.

Proof:

1. Application of the given condition to eigenvectors: Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$.
   Then $\phi(v) = \lambda \cdot v$.
2. Take the eigenvector as $w$: If we take $w$ as an eigenvector, then $\phi(w) = \lambda \cdot w$ also holds.
3. Substitution into the given equation: If we substitute this information into the given equation, we get
   $\langle\phi(v), w\rangle + \langle v, \phi(w)\rangle = 0$, which is equivalent to $\langle \lambda \cdot v, w\rangle + \langle v, \lambda \cdot w\rangle = 0$. Since $\lambda$ is a scalar, we can factor it out, and we get $\lambda \cdot (\langle v, w\rangle + \langle v, w\rangle) = 0$, which corresponds to $2 \cdot \lambda \cdot \langle v, w\rangle = 0$.

Conclusion:

Since $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors, they are not the zero vector, and consequently $\langle v, w\rangle$ is not equal to zero. Therefore, $\lambda$ must be equal to zero.

Here I know my conclusion has to be wrong, since i think i know, that different eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue can be linearly independent making $\langle v, w\rangle = 0$ , meaning $\lambda$ can be non-zero.

I also tried proving it, using the norm but could not justify why v=w, making use of it this way.

So, some feedback would be greatly appreciated. What lacks the proof? Is there a better way go about solving this problem?

Comment: You can take $v = w$, then the inner product will be nonzero

Comment: How come, that is allowed? Would I not lose generality? if not, why?

Comment: Because your second condition holds for all vectors in $V$

Comment: Why not just use $w=v$?

Comment: Since I still fail to see, how that could be inferred that from the given conditions.

Comment: Your second condition is (with different variable names to make it more explicit): It holds for all $x, y$ in $V$ that $\langle\phi(x), y\rangle + \langle x, \phi(y)\rangle = 0$. You can pick $x = v$ and $y = v$ so that $\langle\phi(v), v\rangle + \langle v, \phi(v)\rangle = 0$, because $v \in V$.

Comment: But that would only proof the statement if w = v are the same?  If w!=v, as far as i know, i do not think, that i have had a guarantee that <v,w> is not zero. Since even eigenvectors of the same eigenvalue can be linearly independent, making <v,w> =0. Maybe i fail seeing something basic again.

Comment: You are failing in terms of logic, not linear algebra. If someone gives you a promise: 'If you do such and such, every person named 'John' will be thankful to you,' then you can deduce, particularly, if I do such and such, 'John Mayer' will be thankful. That's what you need to do here. They promised something for every v, w. So, particularly, the promise should hold for the cases where v = w. Note that you're assuming it toward contradiction! You assume that the condition holds, but not the promise. and you get that such situation is not possible. Hence the promise should always hold.

Comment: You are not trying to make a statement about all pairs of vectors. You are trying to show that there are no non-zero eigenvalues. You would only lose generality if you tried to prove that the second condition was true for all $v, w$ given that it was true for $v=w$.

Comment: Yes, now I see the flaw, thank you very much!